# Footer doesn't stick to the bottom (Angular.js application)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, footer

So i built this website (using Angularjs) and for whatever reason, in one of the pages, the footer is keep floating no matter whatever i do.

You can see the issue here:
http://www.deliverightlogistics.com/howitworks

While if you go here, you see the footer positioned in the right place:
http://www.deliverightlogistics.com/ourprocess

The weird part is that given that they both generated into the same Angular content (ng-view), i can't find the reason why i have this issue in one page and not the other.

Keep in mind that I would need a change that would fix the problem but not causing other pages' footer to 'misbehave'.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Angular issue, but a CSS one. In your style.css, you have both `#howitworks_second` and `#howitworks_second article` positioned absolutely. Take those declarations out, add a `clear: both;` to the footer, and your footer pops back to the bottom.

Comment: What you mean to take them out? If i do that, I loose the original design and it screw up the bg images. anything i can do while maintaining this view?